# Function in R does not return vector

Tags: r, function

I am sure this is a really dumb question with a simple answer, but I have been banging my head against the desk for an hour now.  The goal is to write a simple function that returns a vector of n length consisting of integers spaces as evenly as possible, from 1 to k.  So:

```
place_in_groups <- function(n, k){
  rate = (n - 1) / (k - 1)
  vect <- round(seq(from = 1, to = n, by = rate), 0)
  return(vect)
}
```

When I run the lines inside the function on the outside of the function, it does what I want it to do: creates a vector with the appropriate values.  But when I run it inside the vector, I get the actual values, not the vector:

> place_in_groups(4,5)

```
[1] 1 2 2 3 4
```

As I said, I'm sure it is something obvious I'm doing wrong, but it is also something I'm obviously in need of learning.

Comment: check `length.out` parameter of `seq`. I guess `round(seq(1, n, length.out=k))` is enough

Comment: Check `seq(from = 1, to = n, by = rate)`. It creates a vector of evenly spaced values. Then you round those values to get what the function outputs. There's nothing wrong with the function. What would be your expected output?

Comment: I'm hoping to get an object "vect" that contains the list of integers.  Instead, I'm just getting the integers.

Comment: Just an aside, I do not think you need to use `return()` here. R will return the last line executed automatically.

Comment: The object `vect` doesn't exist outside the function. You can create one by assgning the function result like Dan shows in his answer. Then yes, you will have a vector named `vect` in the `globalenv`. Until then `vect` exists only in the environment of the fucntion and ceases to exist as soon as the function exits.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I knew it was something obvious.  So I would need x <- place_in_groups(5, 15)?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not shure I undestand the question correctly. Try `str()` on your results. What you are getting is a vector.

```
vect <- place_in_groups(4,5)
str(vect)
num [1:5] 1 2 2 3 4
```

What do you want to do with the vector, or what is your challenge?

Comment: I think it was answered above.  I needed to assign it like you suggested.  Like I said, an obviously stupid question, but something I obviously needed to learn!